# Passing Data back to First Form from Second Form and a class using delegates in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, windows-forms-designer

From FormA I call FormB using `frmB.Show();`

In FormB, I have two textboxes. Assume User enters some data in those two textboxes.
I need to add this to a ListBox on FormA.

To achieve this I have created a delegate instance and called it in FormA after creation of frmB object - which works fine.

In FormB, Class1 object is created and one of its method is called which also needs to access/update the ListBox in FormA.

I can't create an instance for Class1 in FormA as Class1 instance is created in FormB. I tried to assign Class1 delegate instance to FormB instance but it is not working.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: In what respect is it 'not working'?

Answer (score 0):

I would expose an event in FormB that you invoke when you need to update FormA. Before FormA calls `formBInstance.Show()` you can hook up a delegate to the event handler to handle what you need to do in FormA: `formBInstance.UpdateEvent += myDelegateEventHandler`.
So, when FormB needs to update FormA, you simply fire off that event, and the delegate will run as expected under FormA.

Edit to show some more code!

FormB.cs:

```
    // You can add more parameters to this to pass any data you need
    // in addition to the object sender you pass back
    public delegate void UpdateEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)

    public class FormB : Form
    {

        public event UpdateEventHandler Update;

        private void update()
        {
            // do your updates to formB here
            InvokeUpdateEvent(objectThatContainsUsefulData);
        }

        protected void InvokeUpdateEvent(object sender)
        {
            var handler = UpdateEvent;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(sender, null);
        }
    }
```

FormA.cs:

```
    public class FormA : Form
    {

        private void myUpdateDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do your updates that formA will require here
        }

        public void methodCallingFormB()
        {
            // Do whatever you need to set up for creating form B
            var formB = new FormB();
            formB.UpdateEvent += myUpdateDelegate;
            formB.Show();
        }
    }
```

I hope that all makes sense to you. Check out the [MSDN Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more help!

Comment: i didnot used event but with delegates iam able to do it for formB but for new class object called in formB ,i am unable to that.

Comment: Use events, it will make you life so much easier. Pushing data when required, and invoking events is far more efficient and results in simpler code than in trying to pass references in constructors and the like.

Comment: thanks alexander , i dint worked with events ok i will try now.

Comment: it is working (for second form data to first form ) but for my problem, that is if another class which is called from second form and it also wants to send data to firstform . how to do that ?

Comment: Well, the new class could always take a reference to FormB. Make the InvokeEventHandler public so you call call it from your class.

Comment: ok but,i cant call InvokeEventHandler in class as it can only visible by creating object to formB but by creating object in Class it becomes loop because in formB this class object has been created..

Comment: No, don't create it. Pass it in. In FormB: `var obj = MyClass(this)`
Now you have a parameter of type `FormB` in your constructor of `MyClass`.

Comment: thank you ..is there any way with out passing to constuructor.?